# Debbugging for GRPC Service is not available when there are more than one projects in docker-compose.yml

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, rider

I'm facing a problem with developing a microservices application using .NET and Rider. My solution (.sln) has two projects - an ASP.NET Blazor Server app and an ASP.NET GRPC Service.

When I add only the GRPC project to my docker-compose, the debugger works fine and I can attach breakpoints. However, when I add another project to docker-compose, the web app, the debugger works for the Blazor project; But the breakpoint icon in the GRPC service transforms into a gray  icon and I get an error when I hover on that breakpoint placed in the GRPC service:

`Didn't find the associated module for the breakpoint T:\LatestBargeh\Services\Users.API\Services\GreeterService.cs:16,2`

[Error in Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBlu.png)

Here's my docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  users.api:
    image: users.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Users.API/Dockerfile

#  wapp.server:
#    image: wapp.server
#    build:
#      context: .
#      dockerfile: Wapp.Server/Dockerfile
```

The second service is the web app, and the first one is the GRPC service.

I would really appreciate your support in solving this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: According to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-101037/Debbugging-is-not-available-in-Docker-Compose-projects-when-there-are-more-than-one), the  icon being displayed is a false sign and debugging works. The Rider team has mentioned that this problem is due to running two debugger sessions, and they are thinking about improving this experience. There is a workaround to fix this problem, by adding a separate `docker-compose.yml` file for the GRPC service, but it's not necessary.